# Key Logger with Java

Tags: java, keylogger

I have created this code and this is Code is Working Perfectly Fine but Output Coming through it is not as I expect it gives Mouse Events and Key Presses Events Both But I only want Key Pressed Events

Pressed: Z
Jan 11, 2018 6:46:27 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: keycode_to_unicode [651]: Using keyboard layout 0X0000000004090409.

Released: Z
Jan 11, 2018 6:46:28 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$NativeHookThread enable
INFO: process_mouse_moved [424]: Mouse dragged to 327, 691.

```
package main;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class Main implements NativeKeyListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new Main());
    }


    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
       System.out.println("Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
       System.out.println("Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all logging is enabled. You should turn the logging off as described on the [Logging and Console Output page](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/ConsoleOutput).

Side note: the latest version of class GlobalScreen (2.1.0 at the time of writing) does not have a getInstance() method.

Comment: Hello sir if there is no getinstance() method then how will we implement it??

Comment: You don't "implement" it. `GlobalScreen` has no `getInstance()` method anymore, it's just `GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(...);` now. Download the latest version and see your IDE compain about it.